# Move a file which is constantly in use

Tags: bash, cp, mv, solaris-10

I need to move the whole content of a file (test.log) which is constantly in use. Moving the file could result in an error for the application which is writing to the file.

My approach is to redirect the output to test.log_bck, copy the original file (test.log) to test.log_cp, clear it and then check if there was any data added in the same time the test.log file was cleared. If any data was missing from the _cp file then merge it with the _bck file without redundant data. It is a lot of effort for such an easy task and my question is: is there another, easier / more efficient way to do it.

```
#/usr/bin/bash
#redirect the output to /tmp/logging/test.log_bck
bck(){
        `tail -f /tmp/logging/test.log &> /tmp/logging/test.log_bck`
}

#run it in background
bck &

#copy the original file to test.log_cp
`cp /tmp/logging/test.log /tmp/logging/test.log_cp` | echo "Copped"

#clear the original file
echo "" > /tmp/logging/test.log | echo "Cleared"

#get the PID of the redirection process and check if there are other running and kill them
bck_pid=`ps -ef | grep "tail -f /tmp/logging/test.log" | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' | head -1`

while [ "$bck_pid" != "" ]
do
        echo $bck_pid
        kill $bck_pid | echo "Killed"
        bck_pid=`ps -ef | grep "tail -f /tmp/logging/test.log" | grep -v grep | awk '{print$2}' | head -1`
done

date=$(date '+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M')
cat /tmp/logging/test.log_cp /tmp/logging/test.log_bck > /tmp/logging/test.log_$date

cat -n /tmp/logging/test.log_$date | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2-
```

Comment: Maybe `inotify` can help you. [Some info on it](http://www.infoq.com/articles/inotify-linux-file-system-event-monitoring) and [some other from superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes)

Comment: You suggest watching the file activity after copying the file? Yeah it could work but i forgot to mention that this script needs to run on a solaris 10 machine. No inotify /watchdir on it.

Comment: I don't have Solaris to test, but changing the name of a file shouldn't affect an open file handle referencing it. Just rename the file.

Comment: @chepner As long as it's on the same filesystem...

Comment: I'm not sure it wont affect the handler. I moved with a no data lost result on a test machine but I won't risk it if in some conditions data loss may occur.

Comment: Could you not use a symbolic link and then change where it is pointing ?